# Uploading files via SFTP from the Visual Studio 2012 GUI?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, sftp

I'm pretty sure the answer to this question is 'no' but I have to ask the question in case I'm missing something.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Premium and I'm wondering if there is some method within this app to upload files to my IIS 7.5 server via SFTP.  I already have a solution that uses a 3rd party product for the file transfers but I wanted to see if there is a way within this product to upload files securely (and without Front Page Server extensions).